# Rails 3 & Multilingual context (globalize2?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`globalize2` seems to be a bit dead. It has't been updated for more than a year. Also it does not mention weather it supports Rails 3 or not.

Are there any globalization frameworks for Rails 3? Or any suggestions how to globalize my app without any frameworks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html. This is what we use in our application and it works quite well :) and for database translations you can use new version of globalize - globalize3. You can find it here: https://github.com/galetahub/globalize3

Comment: I could not find how to have multiple languages in a DB. For example I need to store English and Japanese names for a category. And display one of them based on current `I18n.locale`

Comment: I am sorry, I can't think today... I have edited my answer and add information about new version of globalize :)